# How to prove that the Ys are independent under the normality assumption of $\epsilon$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, independence

I am working on a self-study of Cosma Shalizi's "[The Truth About Linear Regression](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/TALR/)". I am currently work my way through Chapter 5, "The Method of Maximum Likelihood for Simple Linear Regression". I need help with question 1, which reads as follows:

> Let $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n$ be generated from the Gaussian-noise simple linear regression model, with the corresponding values of the predictor variable being $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$. Show that if $i \ne j$, then $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are conditionally independent given $(X_i,X_j)$. $Hint:$ If $U$ and $V$ are independent, then $f(U)$ and $g(V)$ are also independent, for any functions $f$ and $g$.

I assume that the solution requires that I show that $P(Y_i|Y_j)$ = $P(Y_i)$, but I am not sure how to describe the conditional probability.

Can someone point me in the right direction of the solution?

Comment: Consider the functions $f(Y_1) = Y_1 - (\beta_0+\beta_1 X_1)$ and $g(Y_2)=Y_2-(\beta_0+\beta_1 X_2).$